# Altertative solution to require dinamically in React-Native

Tags: react-native, require

I have a vector of strings and I want to use each element of that vector with require like that

```
for(var i = 0; i< happy_songs.melodies.length;++i)
      {
         var track = '../resources/'
         track += happy_songs.melodies[i]
        console.log(track)
        var song = require(`../resources/${happy_songs.melodies[i]}`)
}
```

I have tried several syntax approaches but none of them worked, always having a syntax error at the require.
Is there any alternative solution to require which can do the job I want ?

PS: I don't know if this matters but those lines of code are used in an async function.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a aux var as:

var songSource= [path1,path2,...] and use the index as interator to use dinamically

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding my code, please ?